# Error in Image caching with Image Caching Library - JetImageLoader

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, caching, image-caching

I am trying to implement image caching for my "WINDOWS 10 UNIVERSAL APP".
But when using that package I am getting an How to handle this.

Reference used is sample app in https://github.com/artem-zinnatullin/jet-image-loader

> Error: Reference to Type `IsolatedStorageFile` claims that it it
>   defined in 'microlib' but it could not be found.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What is the error, in text? Images aren't the best way to get your message across to everyone.

Comment: Yeah , thanks Edited question with error message.